# Volume calculations always resulting in 0

Tags: c++

I am new to programming in the C language. I'm calculating the volume of a truncated cone within a cone, and I find that the program always returns 0.

The program contains functions within other functions.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h> 

int AreaCirculo ( float radio ){
if ( radio <= 0 ){ 
throw 1; 
} 
int aux = M_PI * pow (radio,2) ;
     return aux ;
}           

int VolumenCono ( float r, float h ){
if ( h <= 0 ){
    throw 2 ; 
}

int aux = (((1/3 )* AreaCirculo (r)) * h );
return aux;
} 
 int RadioMenor (float R, float H, float h){
if ( H < h){
throw 3;
}
if ( R <= 0){
throw 4;
  }
 if ( h <= 0){ // No hay ConoTruncado 
throw 5;
    }
if ( H <=0 ){
   throw 6;
}
int aux = (( R * h) / H ) ;
   return aux;
}
  int VolumenConoTruncado ( float R, float H, float h){
int aux2 = VolumenCono (R,H) - VolumenCono (( RadioMenor (R,H,h)),h);
    return aux2;
}
 int main (){
   float R,H,h;
printf ( " THIS PROGRAM CALCULATE THE VOLUME OF A TRUNCATED CONE IN A CONE.\n");
printf ( " Enter the  Radio : ");
scanf ("%f",&R);
printf ( " Enter the tallest: ");
scanf ("%f",&H);
printf ( " Enter the lower height : ");
scanf ("%f",&h);

try {
    int auxi = VolumenConoTruncado (R,H,h);
    printf ( " El Volumen del cono truncado es es %i.\n",auxi);
}
catch ( int CodigoError){
    switch (CodigoError){
        case 1 :  printf ( " ERROR :  El radio no puede ser menor o igual a cero . \n"); break;
        case 2 : printf ( " ERROR :  La altura no puede ser menor o igual a cero . \n"); break;
        case 3 : printf ( "La altura menor no puede ser mayor a la mayor.\n"); break;
        case 4 : printf ( "El radio no puede ser menor o igual  cero "); break;
        case 5 : printf ( "La altura del cono truncado no puede ser menor a cero"); break;
        case 6 : printf ( "La altura no puede ser menor o igual a cero "); break;
    }
}
system ("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you're new, you probably didn't want to tag this with the vastly different [c++] language tag.

Comment: what formula are you using to calculate the volume?  I would suspect the volume calculation would be in three parts.  1) calculate the volume of the complete cone 2) calculate the volume of the truncated tip cone 3) final volume = total volume - truncated tip volume.  In general, that should be 3 very simple code blocks

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ if this is a C program?

Comment: Yeah , It's what I do in this line                                                                               int aux2 = VolumenCono (R,H) - VolumenCono (( RadioMenor (R,H,h)),h); @user3629249

Comment: given the calculation of the volume of a cone (given the height and radius) is: v = hπr2/3   I'm not seeing that formula in the code

Comment: Exceptions are compiled in C ++ @DavidSchwartz

Comment: The volume of a cone: 1/3 * AreaCirculo (R) * h , It is the formula that makes me @user3629249

Comment: @ChristianEscobarF So this is a C++ program? Why did you mention you were new to programming in C and tag this `C` then -- to throw people off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
int aux = (((1/3 )* AreaCirculo (r)) * h );
```

`1/3` will evaluate to `0`, so `aux` will also always be zero.

Change to:

```
int aux = (((1.0/3) * AreaCirculo(r)) * h);
```

Comment: Thank you, finally compiled me. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because you are mixing floats and ints as in this line:

```
int aux = (( R * h) / H )
```

Note that integers *truncate* fractions:

```
int x = 1.0/2.0;    // x = 0;
```

Comment: Thank You, but I have declared     float , and follow the same